# MySQL increase field by count of REGEXP matches

Tags: mysql, regex, count, match

I am trying to construct a complex query. I have a table, and in that table, I would like to add an artificial field, `match_count`, using `SELECT *,match_count FROM`. That's not the problem. The problem is this: I have several regular expressions, and I would like to increase  the match_count with each regular expressions found. These expressions are to be applied to several fields of the table, like `param1 REGEXP "reg1"` and `param2 REGEXP "reg2"`, and `param1 REGEXP "reg3"`. Columns can be re-used, as can be the expressions, but the match_count field should correspond to the number of matches.

If possible, it would also be cool if, if a column matches a regular expression several times, the match count were increased not by one, but by the number of these matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum the results of the REGEXP expressions:

```
SELECT *,
    param1 REGEXP "reg1" +
    param2 REGEXP "reg2" +
    param1 REGEXP "reg3" AS match_count
FROM
```

---

> If possible, it would also be cool if, if a column matches a regular expression several times, the match count were increased not by one, but by the number of these matches.

I don't think it's possible in MySQL. It is however possible in many general purpose languages.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that a positive match equals 1.

Comment: Although I'd like to note that this syntax does not work without using parentheses for each summand and also for the summing expression.